# Are there any gaseous monopropellants?

Tags: chemistry, monopropellant

There are numerous liquid monopropellants: Hydrazine, Hydrogen Peroxide, Nitrous Oxide, Isopropyl Nitrate, and more.

There are of course also solid monopropellants. (Edit: composite propellants not monopropellants.) The Space Shuttle used [APCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonium_perchlorate_composite_propellant) in its solid boosters, but there are many other solid chemicals possible, even "[Rocket Candy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket_candy)" using sugars.

However, I have never heard of a gaseous monopropellant.

Do they exist? Is there something in chemistry that makes this highly unlikely? Cannot imagine how or why and I am extremely curious about this.

Edit Note: Any substance can be a gas at the right temperature and pressure. I'm looking for gaseous substances at normal temperatures, and stored at relatively high pressure.

Note, cold gas thrusters don't count. Those have no chemical reaction whatsoever. A gaseous monopropellant has to decompose from a catalyst or else burn more conventionally like Isopropyl Nitrate.

Comment: The Shuttle SRBs were not a monopropellant. Their propellant contained aluminum fuel and ammonium perchlorate oxidizer, along with a smattering of other components. This is actually called out in the link you provided "Ammonium perchlorate composite propellant is a composite propellant, meaning that it has both fuel and oxidizer combined into an homogeneous mixture,"

Comment: you might ask the "is there something in chemistry" part of this question at the Chemistry StackExchange.  I imagine that there's an energy consideration about a gas being more likely to have already decomposed into its "burned" constituents, but I was never a very good chemist.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I see, well I don't know anywhere near enough about chemistry to even think of nitpicking this. Might as well make an edit to the OP. I have similar doubts from often seeing liquid solutions described as separate ions and wonder if these are actually two different chemicals in a homogenous mixture, or somehow they can be considered one since the ions should attract and stick to each other.

Answer (score 7):

All rocket propellants end up in the gas phase and are stored in the liquid or solid phases aboard rockets. Many propellants could easily be stored in the gas phase aboard a rocket, but they are not for several reasons. Gases are far less dense than liquids and the size of the tanks required would be prohibitively heavy. Using high pressure does not help much either, as the walls have to be made thicker in many cases. In addition some propellants have a high boiling point making gas phase storage highly inconvenient or impractical.

If you really want a gas phase monopropellant rocket use hydrazine gas >114 degrees C in a heated tank (don't try this at home!) but it won't be very effective as the gas will run out quickly. Or if you want something that is a gas at room temperature try fluorine trichloride just heat it to 180 degrees C and it will decompose (definitely don't try this at home!!)

In summary Gaseous mono propellants don't exist because nobody has been foolish enough to investigate them in the same sense that there are no lorries on the roads with wheels less than a millimetre diameter.

Comment: I forgot the note that all substances are gasses at the right combination of temperature and pressure. Will edit the OP. I realize gasses are far less dense, but iirc there are still some tiny sats that use cold gas because liquid tanks need a gas pressurization tank anyway and all of that would be too heavy for it. But mostly my q is of curiosity. Why would gaseous monoprop chemicals apparently not exist?

Comment: @DrZ214 likely due to performance reasons; liquids are far denser than gasses, so why would you limit performance by going with the low-density option? I mean, you *could* do a hydrolox engine with gases but it would be incredibly impractical.

Comment: Gaseous mono propellants don't exist because nobody has been foolish enough to investigate them in the same sense that there are no lorries on the roads with wheels less than a millimetre diameter. If you really want a monopropellant gas one could probably be found. How about Fluorine trichloride - a gas at room temperature and just needs heating to 180 to disintegrate...

Comment: @Slarty This comment of yours should be put in the answer, i.e. No one does it because it's a ridiculous idea.

Comment: @Oranic Marble - yes thanks thats a good idea